# CSS Fixed nav menu behind content

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, nav

After looking at some posts related to z-index and menus showing behind content I couldn't find the reason why it's still not working for me.

Basically when we scroll, the menu get fixed on the top but doesn't show over this gallery 
http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/index.html that I'm using. However It works normally with other content as shown in the example below.

Here the example http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-floating-navigation-menu/demo/complete.html

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is the header you are refering to, set a higher `z-index` and `position: fixed`. You will also need to set `width: 100%;` See example below

```
.header {
height: 25px;
line-height: 24px;
font-size: 13px;
background: #000;
opacity: 0.9;
text-transform: uppercase;
z-index: 1000;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

**EDITED**

```
nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.882353);
left: 0px;
width: 950px;
z-index: 1000;
background-position: initial initial;
background-repeat: initial initial;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want fixed. The nav menu as in the semi-transparent box and it's contents?

Comment: Set `z-index: 1000;` on the `nav`. I just tried it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It worked that's great ! how could I not add this property on nav I can't believe. 
Thank you very much !!!!